# Why HTML5 Nested Element <main> is Invalid

Tags: html

Why is it invalid to use no more than one `<main>` element per page? For, example, if an `<article>` can have both a nested `<header>` and `<footer>` element, why not a `<main>` as well?

Example:

```
<article>
  <header> ... </header>
  <main> ... </main>
  <footer> ... </footer>
</article>
```

[image: W3.org html validation result: error]

**Edit**: And, I guess my follow question is, given the code example, what should be used in its stead?

Comment: Because it's supposed to signify the main portion of the document, the core of what the current page is about. Important e.g. for screen readers and other programs that try to extract only the most important contents from a page. MDN is a great source for questions like this, always remember to check them out first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow document [HTML5 main attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) on Mozilla:

> The HTML  element represents the main content of  the  of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to, or expands upon the central topic of a document or the central functionality of an application. This content should be unique to the document, excluding any content that is repeated across a set of documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms (unless the document's main function is as a search form).

Note:

- `<main>` must not be a descendent of an `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` element.
- Only one main element can be used per document.